# Set edge attribute of one bipartite projection based on other bipartite projection

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph

I am doing some work with bipartite projections and onemode networks in igraph. Is there a way to label the edges of one onemode network (network of artists below) using the vertices of the other (network of hometowns below)?

I want to do something like the below, but am worried it will not scale as the number of artist nodes expand and relationships between hometowns begin to appear (e.g., artists who split time between two towns).

Thanks!

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     as_data_frame, groups, union
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tibble':
#> 
#>     as_data_frame
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union

df <- tibble(user = c("Mac Miller", "Wiz Khalifa", "Arizona Zervas", "Lil Wayne", "Birdman", "Logic"), hometown = c("Pittsburgh", "Pittsburgh", "DC", "New Orleans", "New Orleans", "DC"))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df) %>% 
    igraph::set_vertex_attr(., name = "type", value = V(.)$name %in% df$hometown) %>% 
    bipartite_projection()

igraph::get.edgelist(g$proj1)
#>      [,1]             [,2]         
#> [1,] "Mac Miller"     "Wiz Khalifa"
#> [2,] "Arizona Zervas" "Logic"      
#> [3,] "Lil Wayne"      "Birdman"

g1 <- igraph::set.edge.attribute(graph = g$proj1, name = "hometown", value = get.vertex.attribute(g$proj2)$name)

get.edgelist(g1)
#>      [,1]             [,2]         
#> [1,] "Mac Miller"     "Wiz Khalifa"
#> [2,] "Arizona Zervas" "Logic"      
#> [3,] "Lil Wayne"      "Birdman"

get.edge.attribute(g1)
#> $weight
#> [1] 1 1 1
#> 
#> $hometown
#> [1] "Pittsburgh"  "DC"          "New Orleans"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>